# Why would $f(a)>0$ or $f(b)>0$ imply $f(x)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I have an exercise in my notebook and I don't understand one thing in the answer to it:

Exercise: Show that $$||f||_{L^p}:=\biggl(\int^b_a|f(x)|^p|dx\biggr)^{1/p}$$

defines a norm on $C([a,b])$ for any $1\leq p \lt \infty$.

So the bit from the answer that concerns me is an explanation of why would $f(x)>0$ if $f(a)$ or $f(b)$. Here is the part of the answer:

Suppose that $f\in C([a,b])$ with $\int^b_a|f(x)|^pdx=0$

but $f\neq 0$. Then $f(c)\neq 0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$. [If $f(a)>0$ then $f(x)>0$ for some $x>c$, since $f$ is continuous: likewise if $f(b)>0$ then $f(x)>0$ for some $c<b$.]

Here I don't understand why would $f(a)>0 \Rightarrow f(x)>0$ since $f$ is continuous. Is there some property of continuous functions I don't know? My reasoning for this, although not rigorous, is that if $f(a)>0$, then it should be that in the small area after $f(a)$, there are some values of $f$ that take values bigger than $0$, otherwise the function would have a "bump" or "dot" at $f(a)$ which would make it discontinuous.

Comment: The key point is "for some $x$", ie, $f$ is continuous at $x=x_0$ implies there exists an (punctured) open ball $B'(x_0,\epsilon)$ centered at $x_0$ such that $f(y)\to f(x_0)$ for all points $y$ in this ball. You can use this to ensure that if $f(x_0)\neq 0$, there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ where the values taken by $f$ have the same sign as $f(x_0)$

Comment: More strongly, you can ensure that for a continuous map $f$ and a point $x=x_0$, you can approximate $f(x_0)$ with arbitrary precision using points in a neighborhood of $x_0$, the formal statement of which is the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit: $\forall\epsilon\gt 0~\exists\delta\gt 0\colon 0\lt|x-x_0|\lt\delta\implies 0\lt|f(x)-f(x_0)|\lt\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Because $f$ is continuous, and so if at some point $x_0\in[a,b]$ we have that $f(x_0)=c>0$ then there is a neighborhood $(x_0-\delta ,x_0+\delta )$ of $x_0$ such that $f(x)>c/2$ for all $x\in(x_0-\delta ,x_0+\delta ) \cap [a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Mathematical reasoning so the question of correctness does not arise.

There exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)| < f(a)$ for $a<x<a+\delta$. So $f(x)\geq f(a)-|f(x)-f(a)| >0$ for any $x$ with $a<x<a+\delta$. Similar argument works for points near $b$.

Comment: well if not mathematically, then intuitively did I think of it correctly? Also, why would $x>0$?

Comment: @ДарияСоколова Answer corrected.